# Why doesn't a where condition work correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this procedure and it should return records based on give dates and few other inputs. First it places a branch_ID in a temp table @branches and then pick that branch_ID from temp table but it returns records for all branches not only for the one that has been picked. Why ? But when i put static Branch_ID i.e. 3 then it picks for that.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RejectedFiles] 
(  
 @FromDate SMALLDATETIME,  
 @ToDate SMALLDATETIME,  
 @OfficeID INT=0,  
 @Type INT=0
)  
AS  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @Branches TABLE  
(  
 BranchID INT  
)  

IF @Type = 1  
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE OrganizationID = @OfficeID  
END  

IF @Type = 2  
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE CompanyID = @OfficeID  

END  

IF @Type = 3  
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @Branches SELECT BranchID From vw_OrganizationTree WHERE BranchID = @OfficeID  
END  

    SELECT C.CompanyName,B.BranchName,E.EmployerName,FE.EmployeeUniqueID,pcr.EmployerUniqueID,
         FE.IncomeFixedComponent,FE.IncomeVariableComponent,  
         S.StatusDescription, FE.IsRejected, FE.ID 'EdrID'
    From File_EdrEntries FE JOIN PAFFiles pe ON pe.ID = FE.PAFFile_ID
    inner join File_PCREntries pcr on pe.ID=pcr.PAFFile_ID 
    JOIN Employers E ON E.EmployerID = pcr.EmployerUniqueID
    JOIN Branches B ON B.BranchID = E.Branch_ID JOIN companies C ON C.COMPANYID = B.COMPANY_ID  
    JOIN Statuses S ON S.StatusID = FE.Status_ID
    where fe.IsRejected=1 
    AND E.Branch_id = (Select Branch_ID from @Branches)

END
```

Comment: You should post sample data and table definition.

Answer (score 1):

Note :Please confirm that it is not typo

The Problem with the column Name i.e Column Name declare in `@Branches` table is different than the used in where clause.

Column Name in  `@Branches` table

```
DECLARE @Branches TABLE  
(  
 BranchID INT  
)
```

And in where clause

```
...
AND E.Branch_id = (Select Branch_ID from @Branches)
```

There may be possibility that `@Branches` table may have multiple rows so instead of comparing equality you should use `IN` of `EXISTS`

```
AND E.Branch_id IN (Select BranchID from @Branches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using this temp table, you should be able to compose everything into a single query:

```
...
JOIN Statuses S ON S.StatusID = FE.Status_ID
where fe.IsRejected=1 
AND EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM vw_OrganizationTree v
   WHERE v.BranchID = e.BranchID AND
     (@Type = 1 and v.OrganizationID = @OfficeID) or
     (@Type = 2 and v.CompanyID = @OfficeID) or
     (@Type = 3 and v.BranchID = @OfficeID)
   )
```

---

And as JaydipJ alludes to, the reason why your current code isn't working is because here:

```
AND E.Branch_id = (Select Branch_ID from @Branches)
```

There is no column called `Branch_ID` in the `@Branches` table. So it becomes a reference to a column in the outer query (if there were more than one such column, it would generate an error). And so it has effectively become:

```
AND E.Branch_id = E.Branch_ID
```

Which is why it returns all rows. This is why it's always a good idea to use prefixed column names when using subqueries. This:

```
AND E.Branch_id = (Select x.Branch_ID from @Branches x)
```

Would have generated an error about a non-existent column and given a clue to why it wasn't working.